# Python: Heapify k-order min-heap?

Tags: python, algorithm, heap

I'm creating a class for a K-Order Min-heap. I'm storing the heap as a list. I'm having trouble with implementing remove_min. I know that the process of removing the minimum of a heap is:

1. Remove first element. This is the minimum.
2. Swap the first element and the last element.
3. Bubble the new top element down until it satisfies the heap property.

So I need a remove_min and a helper function, bubbledown. I can't use heapq because it only accounts for binary heaps and this class needs to take a k-order heap. Here's what I have so far:

```
class KHeap:
    def __init__(self, lst=[], k=2):
        self.heap = []
        self.k = k #order of heap
        for v in lst:
            self.insert(v)

    def children(self, i): #returns a list of the children of the item in index i
        heap = self.heap
        result = []
        for x in range(self.k*i+1, self.k*i+self.k+1):
            if x<len(heap):
                result.append(heap[x])
            else:
                pass
        return result

    def parent(self, i): #returns the parent of item in index i
        heap = self.heap
        if i==0:
            return None
        result = i//self.k
        return heap[result]

    def bubbleup(self, i): 
        if i == 0:
            return None
        elif self.heap[i] < self.parent(i):
            self.heap[i], self.heap[i // self.k] = self.heap[i // self.k], self.heap[i]
            self.bubbleup(i // self.k)

    def insert(self, value): #use bubbleup
        self.heap.append(value)
        self.bubbleup(len(self.heap)-1)

    def bubbledown(self, i, d=1):
        if i==0:
            return None
        small = i
        for k in range(self.children(i)):
            if self.heap[k]<self.heap[small]:
                small = k
        self.heap[i], self.heap[small] = self.heap[small], self.heap[i]
        self.bubbledown(small)

    def remove_min(self): #use bubbledown
        if len(self.heap) == 0:
            return None
        if len(self.heap) == 1:
            return self.heap.pop()
        minimum = self.heap[0]
        self.heap[0] = self.heap.pop()
        self.bubbledown(0)
        return minimum
```

Now, when I remove_min, the result isn't heapified. For example, if I have a ternary heap `[1, 10, 18, 22, 15, 30], k=3` and I remove the minimum, the result is `[30, 10, 18, 22, 15]`. It seems like the element that I move to the top never gets bubbled down.

Comment: what is your problem? or error?

Comment: When I remove_min, the result isn't heapified. For example, if I have a ternary heap `[1, 10, 18, 22, 15, 30], k=3` and I remove the minimum, the result is `[30, 10, 18, 22, 15]`. It seems like the element that I move to the top never gets bubbled down. (I'll put this in the original post)

Comment: The first problem is that in your remove_min, you call self.bubbledown(0). and in your bubbledown, the first line is if i == 0: return None. Therefore, everytime you call bubbledown(0), nothing changes. fix that and try again.

Comment: If i==0 shouldn't be my base case, what should it be? If I remove it I get index errors

Comment: If you bubbledown, then I guess the base case is the case where you cannot move down anymore, which should be the case of no children.

Comment: In `bubbledown`, you're moving *down* the heap. So you should be checking to see if `heap[i]` has any children. Also, you might want to check your parent calculation. When your root node is at 0, the calculation for parent is `(i-1)/k`. For example, when `k==2`, the parent of nodes 1 and 2 is 0. But if you use `i/k` (which it appears you're doing), you get a value of 1 for node 2's parent.

Answer (score 0):

So I post a iteration version, which can solve the i == 0 problem.

```
def bubbledown(self, i, d=1):
    small = i
    size = len(self.heap)
    while (i < size):
        // find the smallest child
        for k in range(self.children(i)):
            if self.heap[k] < self.heap[small]:
                small = k
        self.heap[i], self.heap[small] = self.heap[small], self.heap[i]
        // stop here
        if small == i:
            break
        else:
            i = small
```